# How do I add a functional scroll arrow to an existing lightbox?

Tags: jquery, html, css, lightbox

I have a client who has photography site with over 10,000 photo files on it. [Here](http://andrew-weiss.com/images/primus/index.htm) is an example of one of his many pages. If you click one of the thumbnails you will notice that it prompts the lightbox. The problem is that there is NO scroll arrow, so you have to click out of the photo to see the new one zoomed in everytime. All of his photos are organized and in the lightbox how they should be.

The simplest solution seems to be to add a scroll arrow to the existing lightbox structure. How would I do that?

I have a similar question to this [on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6448277/recommendation-for-mass-abundance-file-management) but it just dawned on me to approach it this way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why reinvent the wheel?  Why not install an existing plugin like [prettyPhoto](http://www.no-margin-for-errors.com/projects/prettyphoto-jquery-lightbox-clone/)?

It includes the scrolling arrows, slideshow, lightbox, and an optional mini-thumbnail gallery within the lightbox.

Comment: so I can just plug that into my already existing lightbox structure?

Comment: @LightningWrist:  Yes, the plugin is very flexible.